# Python module workdays

Tags: python, datetime

The python function `workday()` in the module [workdays](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/workdays/) has an inconvenient input format:

```
workday(date(year=2009,month=12,day=28),10,[date(year=2009,month=12,day=29)])
```

I would prefer to input the dates as `2009, 12, 28`.

My `holiday.xlsx` list is read in as entries with: `datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0).`

Thus I am trying to figure out how to align this format to work with the `workday()` function.

Any advice would be well received.

Comment: You can write it however you like if you write a function to call properly.

Comment: What is the "python module `workday()`"? That's not something that's in the standard library, as far as I can see. I do see a [workday**s**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/workdays/) module in PyPI. Is this what you're using?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/workdays/ it works out the end date, if you specify start date and duration. IE it excludes weekends and holidays.

Comment: Ignacio, please may you provide an example of how to call the function correctly?

Comment: I tried this: PP = workday((24, 12, 2009,"%d %m %Y"),10,([2009, 12, 28],"%d %m %Y"))...still not working.

Comment: Of course not. You can't call the *old* function differently, you need to call the *new* function.

Comment: Praise God and thanks for your help. FINALLY my code worked: PlanCompDate = workday(batchStD.date(), 10, holidays). Where I also converted the "holidays" list to date objects. Learnt a lot thanks guys.

Comment: there is an updated lib -  https://github.com/cadu-leite/networkdays 
exclude weekends and holidays- you mau redefine weekends and valid workdays .

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the `datetime.datetime` object from Excel into a `date` object and feed it to `workday()`:

```
>>> date_from_xlsx = datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0).date()
>>> workday(date_from_xlsx, 10, [date(year=2009, month=12, day=29)])
datetime.date(2016, 5, 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this, you can convert the weird format to string:

Assuming *d* is your variable that prints as '*datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 1, 0, 0)*'

```
   from datetime import datetime

   print(d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')) 
   Output: '2016-05-01'
```

More in [https://appdividend.com/2020/01/21/how-to-convert-datetime-to-string-in-python/#:~:text=Python%20strftime%20%28%29%20is%20an%20inbuilt%20datetime%20module,then%20we%20can%20use%20the%20strftime%20%28%29%20method](https://appdividend.com/2020/01/21/how-to-convert-datetime-to-string-in-python/#:%7E:text=Python%20strftime%20%28%29%20is%20an%20inbuilt%20datetime%20module,then%20we%20can%20use%20the%20strftime%20%28%29%20method).